# Wait after user clicks on button

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I have an input number surrounded by two buttons (-/+) in order to *add* or *remove* quantity from this input. Right after the quantity, I have a *submit button* which launches an *ajax code* from a module that updates the quantity of the product in a cart.

How can I trigger this button after like 1.5s after the user stops clicking/changing the values from this input (to avoid multiple calls), and intercept when the ajax call is done, so that the user can reuse the input?

This is how I'm increasing the value of the input and started to work with. I can't find the logic to do it after increasing the value...

```js
let currentAdding = false;
$(document).on('click', '[data-action="more"]', function() {
  let input = $(this).siblings('input[type="number"]');
  let val = input.val();
  let total = parseInt(val) + parseInt(1);
  input.val(total)
  if (currentAdding === false) {
    $(this).parents('form').find('input[type="submit"]').trigger('click') //this click trigger an ajax call from a module
    //set currentAdding after the ajax is done
    currentAdding = true;
  }
});
```

Comment: start a timer when the user click. Reset the timer every time the user clicks and the timer not ended yet. When the timer ends (so wasn't reset for a while) then trigger whatever funtion you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up with this solution :

```
let currentLess = false;
        var typingTimer = null;
        var doneTypingInterval = 1000;

        $(document).on('click', '[data-action="less"]', function() {
            if(typingTimer !== null) {
                clearTimeout( typingTimer );
            }
            console.log('click less')
            let button = $(this)
            let input = button.siblings('input[type="number"]');
            if(button.siblings('.field--name-variations').length > 0) {
                input = button.siblings('.field--name-variations').find('input');
            }

            let val = input.val();
            const min = input.attr('min')
            let total = parseInt(val)-parseInt(1);
            input.val(val === min ? val : total);
            typingTimer = setTimeout(function() {
                console.log("update")
                //if(currentLess === false) {
                    ajaxAddToCartTrigger(button)
                //}
            }, doneTypingInterval);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something called debouncing in javascript.
Create a function called debounce

```
function debounce(func, delay) {
  var debounceTimer
  return function() {
    var context = this
    var args = arguments
    clearTimeout(debounceTimer)
    debounceTimer = setTimeout(function() { func.apply(context, args); }, delay);
  }
}
```

now you can modify your event handler something like this

```
let currentAdding = false;
$(document).on('click','[data-action="more"]', debounce(function() {
  let input = $(this).siblings('input[type="number"]');
  let val = input.val();
  let total = parseInt(val)+parseInt(1);
  input.val(total)
  if(currentAdding === false) {
   $(this).parents('form').find('input[type="submit"]').trigger('click') //this click trigger an ajax call from a module
   //set currentAdding after the ajax is done
   currentAdding = true;
  }, 1500); // 1.5 seconds delay
});
```

you can read more about debouncing [here](http://geeksforgeeks.org/debouncing-in-javascript/)

Comment: Your code is working, but maybe I wasn't clear, I need the user to be able to click several time on the button, but i'd like to avoid multiple ajax call, not multiple button click